# Navigation on validation failure in Seam/JSF

Tags: java, rest, jsf, seam

I've been playing with [Seam](http://www.seamframework.org/) (2.0.2.SP1) for a few weeks, and I have most of the basics nailed down, but I haven't come up with a decent solution to the following.

Suppose I have a form at `/foo.xhtml`, with a rewrite rule such that URLs like `/foo.seam?id=<fooId>` are converted to `/foo/<fooId>`.  There's a `commandButton` on the form with an action of `#{fooHome.update}`.  I also have a navigation rule in `/foo.page.xml` that redirects back to a nice, bookmark-friendly GET after a successful POST:

```
<navigation from-action="#{fooHome.update}">
    <rule if-outcome="updated">
        <redirect view-id="/foo.xhtml">
            <param name="id" value="#{fooHome.instance.id}"/>
        </redirect>
    </rule>
</navigation>
```

The problem is when a validation error occurs, at which point the navigation rules get skipped, and I end up at `/foo` after the POST.

**My question:  Is there a way to redirect on validation errors, so I end up with a GET request for `/foo/<fooId>` instead of the POST to `/foo`?**

I tried rolling my own validation methods in `fooHome`, returning a "failed" outcome, but I don't really want invalid data getting past the validation phase (and thus into the current conversation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally redisplay the same view on a validation failure, rather than redirect. Assuming that you are using UrlRewrite for the rewrite rules, perhaps you can use an *outbound-rule* so that the */foo/{fooId}* URL is still shown in this case.

Comment: I am indeed using UrlRewrite, but I can't seem to construct such an outbound-rule. <h:form/> uses the current view (/foo) as the action, not the rewritten URL (/foo/<fooId>). Unless I'm missing something (entirely possible), I don't see a way to get <fooId> into an outbound-rule.

Comment: In the end, I just reworked my form to stay on the same view on validation failure, as you suggest. I'm still curious if there's a way to do what I was originally hoping, but this will work for now.